# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function in save button

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a from submit & once I click the following save button it says "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function". It has work properly and suddenly give this issue now.what is the wrong with this?

```
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:$('#crud').submit();" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Save') }}</a>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: you could try `onclick="document.getElementById('crud').submit();"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update this it will work

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('crud').submit();" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Save') }}</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when jQuery is not added to the document or the function is running before jQuery added.

Update:

```
javascript:$('#crud').submit();
```

with :

```
javascript:document.getElementById('crud').submit();
```